# How can i add 16 picturebox in to Groupbox

Tags: c#, picturebox, groupbox

```
     PictureBox[] p = new PictureBox[15];
        for (int i = 0; i == 15; i++)
        {
            p[i] = new PictureBox();
            p[i].Name = "ItemNum" + i.ToString();
            p[i].Location = new Point(0, 0);
            p[i].Size = new Size(10, 10);
            p[i].Visible = true;
            p[i].BackColor = Color.Red;
            this.Controls.Add(p[i]);


        }
```

i couldnt make  Location.How should i write?How can i enhance the top and lef of the location for each picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    p.Location = new Point(10, (i + 1) * 20);
    p.Size = new Size(10, 10);
    p.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(p);
}
```

Use the above code after

```
InitializeComponent();
```

in your Form constructor.

Comment: You have off by one error. +1 though

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel, do you mean initializing with i = 1? (I would be happy to provide an edit if there is any other issue.)

Comment: Op asked for 16 picture boxes, your code would execute 15 times only. I edited your answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks! :) Didn't notice my typo.

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here

- Create the picture box inside of the `for` loop
- the `for` loop is wrong, it never runs.  The 2nd expression determines when the for loops ends.
- Your need to add the new picture to the form/groupBox1

Comment: @Laambi, your are wrong it will never run.  You are correct that the trailing i++ needs to be removed.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. You are correct.

Comment: i couldnt understand can you add the answer